# Nginx redirect to different location with part of the request header

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to redirect certain requests to different location, but with part of the request header, example:
https://example.com/something/value ---> https://example.com/something/index.php?var=value

pseudo-code:

```
location ^~ /something/$value {
    return 301 https://$host/something/index.php?var=$value;
}
```

Comment: Is `something` a fixed string and `value` a variable string?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` only needs to match that part of the URI which is constant. If `/something/index.php` and `/something/value` is the same prefix, then you do not want to use the `^~` modifier, otherwise the PHP file will not be found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Use `rewrite` to capture the "value" part of the URI and append it as an argument.

For example:

```
location /something/ {
    rewrite ^/something/(.*)$ /something/index.php?var=$1 last;
}
```

If you want an external redirection use `rewrite...permanent` instead of `rewrite...last`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.